# travis ci and python ctypes dependency

Tags: python, travis-ci

I wrote a Python wrapper for a C++ library, both of which are on GitHub. The C++ library is not downloadable via package managers, it must be built manually with `make`.

Is it possible to have Travis CI do build tests for my Python wrapper when it requires the C++ .so?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it in the Travis CI docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Projects-from-Source